# Is the absolution from priests still valid if the priest breaks the seal of confession?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments, confession

Suppose a sinner confesses his sins to a priest, receives absolution, completes the penance, but the priest talks about his confessed sins with others. Is the absolution still valid?

Comment: ...yes? Why *wouldn't* it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sacraments consist of matter and form.

For the sacrament of penance they are:

**Matter:** Acts of the Penitent: *Contrition, Confession, and Satisfaction for sins.*

**Form:** Priest saying: *God, the Father of mercies, through the death and resurrection of his Son has reconciled the world to himself and sent the Holy Spirit among us for the forgiveness of sins; through the ministry of the Church, may God give you pardon and peace, and **I absolve you** from your sins in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit."*

If the proper matter, form and intention are observed, the absolution is valid and nothing done afterwards can invalidate it.

Here are some examples of things that make a confession invalid:

- The penitent isn't sufficiently sorry for his sins.
- The penitent doesn't have a firm enough purpose of amendment.
- The penitent conceals a mortal sin or otherwise makes a dishonest confession

> Psalms 140:4 *Incline not my heart to evil words; to make excuses in sins.*

- The priest wasn't validly ordained.
- The priest doesn't say the proper form: *"Ego te absolvo..."*
- The penitent wasn't validly baptized.

> St. Teresa of Avila: “Bad confessions damn the majority of Christians.”

Although even most traditional priests don't follow them today, there are actually quite a number of guidelines priests should follow to determine whether to refuse absolution to a penitent precisely to prevent giving an invalid "absolution" and the penitent dying in their sins.

It is related that padre Pio refused absolution to two thirds of his penitents, often they would come back with a firm resolve never to sin again and then he would grant them absolution.

> Blessed Anna Maria Taigi: “The greater number of Christians today are damned.  The destiny of those dying on one day is that very few, not as many as 10, went straight to Heaven, many remain in Purgatory, and those that were cast into Hell were as numerous as snowflakes in midwinter.”

The fact that you are not aware of the basics about confession suggests you were sadly very poorly catechized, or not at all, and are in danger of perishing due to your ignorance.

I sincerely recommend reading the [Penny catechism](https://vaticancatholic.com/catechism/) to learn the basics of the faith and also to check out Most Holy Family Monastery's [website](https://vaticancatholic.com/vatican-ii-council/) for essential information to save your soul.

<3

Comment: "The greater number of Christians today are damned."  Compare this with John 5:24 and see that, if someone is damned it is precisely because they are not Christians.

Comment: Most Holy Family Monastery is a sedevacantist sect. Avoid.

Comment: @Amatsuki Actually one can and must have moral certainty about the validity of his confession if he has diligently examined his conscience, as St. Alphonsus says. If you are Catholic you have an obligation to confess all mortal sins as soon as possible. In charity I must say that it seems you have drifted far away from Catholic teaching by reading heretical sources, please do go back and read the penny catechism and pray the rosary each day.

Comment: @Glorius That sounds like judging yourself, which Paul said he would not do (1 Corinthians 4:3) and we are supposed to imitate Paul (I Corinthians 11:1-2)

Comment: +1 for discussing sacramental matter and form.

Comment: @Amatsuki what I stated is Catholic teaching, it's not up for discussion. If you reject it you will die in your sins.

Comment: @Glorius I just read the penny catechism last night. I don't think I was baptized correctly with correct form, matter and intention as a baby. Even though I have the copy of the baptismal certificate in a book in my room... something tells me that the baptism was not done correctly, somehow. I see spiritual signs, including the *incurvatus in se* described by St. Augustine which characterizes unbaptized gentiles. If this is the case, please pray for me that Our Lady provide me the grace of water baptism.

Comment: @Amatsuki While it's possible you weren't properly baptised it's pretty unlikely even in the Novus Ordo that they would mess up that bad. Most "spiritual signs" are of the devil, especially if one wants them and doesn't scrutinize them. Read up on St. Theresa of Avila and how she responded to her visions.

Comment: @Glorius Then please pray to Our Lady that I be released from the slavery of habitual mortal sin. And what books by name by St. Teresa of Avila should I read?

Comment: @Amatsuki I recommend this biography: https://youtu.be/R-kf2juM0iY If you want to read her best book it is the Interior Castle.  In order to be saved you first need to convert to the true Catholic faith as taught by the Church for 2000 years, not the new religion which started after Vatican II: See this playlist for crucial information to save your soul: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx7nJ5O4AHdteXuGw3Iam5KHPV8olrUpK

Comment: @Amatsuki You definitely need to pray the rosary every day otherwise you will not be able to stop sinning. If you can, try to pray the whole 15 decades given to St. Dominic and recommended by Our Lady of Fatima (joyful, sorrowful and glorious mysteries) This video should help you overcome sin: https://youtu.be/wwr-u55mKL0 I will definitely pray for you. If you have any other questions you can e-mail me at john.smith.1212888@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

**Is the absolution from priests still valid if the priest breaks the seal of confession?**

The short answer is **yes**, the absolution received in confession remains valid.

The breaking of the seal of confession has no bearing on a valid confession, once absolution has been given by a priest.

The Church takes the seal of confession very seriously and administers harsh penalties to any priest who breaks the seal of confession.

> The sacramental seal is inviolable.  Quoting Canon 983.1 of the Code of Canon Law, the Catechism states, “…It is a crime for a confessor in any way to betray a penitent by word or in any other manner or for any reason” (#2490).  A priest, therefore, cannot break the seal to save his own life, to protect his good name, to refute a false accusation, to save the life of another, to aid the course of justice (like reporting a crime), or to avert a public calamity.  He cannot be compelled by law to disclose a person’s confession or be bound by any oath he takes, e.g. as a witness in a court trial.  A priest cannot reveal the contents of a confession either directly, by repeating the substance of what has been said, or indirectly, by some sign, suggestion, or action.  A Decree from the Holy Office (November 18, 1682) mandated that confessors are forbidden, even where there would be no revelation direct or indirect, to make any use of the knowledge obtained in the confession that would “displease” the penitent or reveal his identity.
>
> Therefore, from the time a person makes the sign of the cross and begins “Bless me father for I have sinned” to the last words of absolution, the information exchanged between the priest and the penitent is protected by the sacramental seal.  Even if a confession is made in a less formal atmosphere or in a less formal way, if a priest imparts absolution, what he absolves is under the sacramental seal never to be revealed by him.
>
> What happens if a priest violates the seal of confession?  The Catechism (#1467) cites the Code of Canon Law (#1388.1) in addressing this issue, which states, “A confessor who directly violates the seal of confession incurs an automatic excommunication reserved to the Apostolic See; if he does so only indirectly, he is to be punished in accord with the seriousness of the offense.”  From the severity of the punishment, we can clearly see how sacred the sacramental seal of confession is in the eyes of the Church.
>
> A beautiful story (perhaps embellished with time) which captures the reality of this topic is the life of St. John Nepomucene (1340-93), the vicar general to the Archbishop of Prague.  King Wenceslaus IV, described as a vicious, young man who easily succumbed to rage and caprice, was highly suspicious of his wife, the Queen.  St. John happened to be the Queen’s confessor.  Although the king himself was unfaithful, he became increasingly jealous and suspicious of his wife, who was irreproachable in her conduct.  Although Wencelaus tortured St. John to force him to reveal the Queen’s confessions, he would not.  In the end, St. John was thrown into the River Moldau and drowned on March 20, 1393. - [Can the seal of confession be broken or the secrets ever be revealed by priests?](https://catholicstraightanswers.com/can-the-seal-of-confession-be-broken-or-the-secrets-ever-be-revealed-by-priests/)

[St. John Nepomucene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_Nepomuk) was martyred defending the seal of confession in 1393 and is the Patron Saint of Confessors! His feast day is May 16.

Comment: How does your extended quote support that "The breaking of the seal of confession has no baring on a valid confession once absolution has been given by a priest."?